# Trying to install Linux kernel headers but getting an error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

I am trying to follow the NVIDIA Driver Installation Quickstart Guide:

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html

The first instruction says:

> The kernel headers and development packages for the currently running
> kernel can be installed with:$ `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

When I try this I get the error:

```
Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.140-tegra
Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.140-tegra'
Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.140-tegra'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Try first `apt search linux-header`, perhaps after `apt-get install apt`

Comment: What is under `/usr/src/` now?

Comment: under ```/usr/src/``` there is ```linux-headers-4.9.140-tegra-linux_x86_64``` and ```linux-headers-4.9.140-tegra-ubuntu18.04_aarch64```

Comment: Maybe this can help out: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/request-install-linux-headers-on-jetson-nano/76237

Comment: Just FYI, have a look at the `gcc` option `-I dir` and its brothers and sisters.

Answer (score 3):

Your version of Ubuntu is running a tegra kernel. The headers for this kernel are not in the Ubuntu repositories (or any other repositories you may have enabled). You will probably need to these before proceeding with the driver installation.

However. NVIDIA Tegra is a small SoC (system on chip) processor AFAIK. Like a Jetson Nano or something. The instructions you linked are for NVIDIA Tesla GPUs which are data center GPUs. Again, AFAIK. Check you are following the right instructions. Also, in those instructions, look at: 'Section 1.1 - Pre-installation requirements', and [this pre install checklist](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions).

[Here](https://paste.debian.net/1168758) is a list of all the different kernel headers in the Ubuntu 20.04 repos (not the same I know). tegra is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can install the appropriate kernel headers, update your packages index. First use the update command.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` again. If this doesn't work, try out

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

which should install the right version.